# How to publish and deploy a .Net Console application in similar way as Web application?

Tags: azure, msbuild, continuous-integration, console-application, azure-devops

We have several Build definitions setup at TFS online (visualstudio.com) which delivers our Web application to several Azure machines (DEV, TEST, AccTest etc..).
It works and they trigger on build events.

BUT: Now we have added a Console Application (Batch exe file) that don't have a publishingProfile. The Build definition builds entire solution (console project is a part of that), but when it comes to Deployment only Web project is deployed in another folder and zipped.

I have read a lot on Stackoverflow and MSDN sites. But could not really find any spot on answers. This must be a common scenario that you have non-web projects in a solution that also needs to be deployed on same server through VSTS.

Comment: Where do you want to deploy/publish the console application to? Using it as webjob of app service?

Comment: About webjob: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs

Answer (score 3):

You can archive the files you want to deploy as a zip file, and specify the zip file as **Package or folder** option in **Azure App Service Deploy** task.

Detail tasks and settings to deploy the .net console app to azure as below:

#### 1. Copy Files task

Source Folder: `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`

Contents: `ProjectName\**` or you can specify the certain file (such as *.exe) to copy

Target Folder: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`

#### 2. Archive Files

Root folder (or file) to archive: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`

Archive type: `zip`
Archive file to create: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/deploy.zip`

#### 3. Azure App Service Deploy

Specify **Azure subscription** and **App Service name** as you set before.

Package or folder: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\deploy.zip`

Now files you copied from .net console project are deployed to your Azure App service.